# Por que o code blocks compila usando g++ num projecto configurado como "C"

Tags: c, compiladores, codeblocks

Estou aprendendo `C` e usando o CodeBlocks,

Fui em
`File > New > Project > "Console Application" > "GO" > Next`

e aparece a pergunta

```
Please select the language you want use.
```

Eu seleciono `C`. mas ao compilar um simples `HelloWord`
aparece no console

```
gcc -Wall -g -std=c11  -c /opt/workspace/learningC/Basics/main.c -o 
g++  -o bin/Debug/Basics obj/Debug/main.o
```

Porque ele está usando o `g++`  ?

Answer (score 0):

Você já usava o codeblocks ou instalou agora? Dê mais detalhes do seu problema.

Verifique se o compilador está selecionado corretamente.

Depois que você selecionou C, clica em next vai aparecer a tela pra configurar o nome do projeto, ai clica em next novamente e aparecerá e seguinte tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Verifique qual compilador está selecionado, essa é a primeira solução que veio na minha cabeça.

Comment: O projeto está certo, assim como compilador. Estou usando Ubuntu 16.04 e CodeBlocks 16.01